# Apply a function on a list by matching arguments names and list names

Tags: r

I have this function:

```
myFun <- function(a,b,d){
  
  if(missing(a)){
    a <- 1
  }
  if(missing(b)){
    b <- 1
  }
  if(missing(d)){
    d <- 1
  }
  
  a + b + d
  
}
```

This is a simplified version, but the spirit is here. Each argument name (i.e. `a`, `b` and `d`) have a meaning for the user and are important here. As they're optional, the function works even if you don't use them all:

```
myFun(a = 1, d = 3)
[1] 5
```

My goal is to apply this function to a named list, with names corresponding to what parameter the value should be applied.
So I'm looking for some function like:

```
some_function(
  input = list(a = 1, d = 3),
  FUN = myFun
)
```

which would behave like: `myFun(a = 1, d = 3)`.

The final aim is to have a function on which I could loop to apply it on various lists:

```
apply(
  list(
    list(a = 1, d = 3),
    list(b = 2, d = 1),
    list(a = 1, b = 2, d = 3)
  ),
  FUN = some_function
)
```

I have a few ideas with the `purrr` package. Unfortunately, this should be done in `base` R.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an input and output example? are the lists nested?

Comment: Do you know about `do.call`?

Comment: @Dason Didn't think about `do.call`! Thanks. This works perfectly; `sapply(list(list(a = 1, d = 3),list(a = 2, b = 4)),FUN = function(input) do.call(myFun,input))`

Comment: Are the missing values always going to default to 1?

Comment: Why not using default arguments instead of `missing`? `myFun <- function(a=1, b=1, d=1) {a + b + d}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved without the need for a wrapper function...

```r
myFun <- function(a,b,d){
  if(missing(a)){
    a <- 1
  }
  if(missing(b)){
    b <- 1
  }
  if(missing(d)){
    d <- 1
  }
  a + b + d
}

input_list <- list(
  list(a = 1, d = 3),
  list(b = 2, d = 1),
  list(a = 1, b = 2, d = 3)
)

results_list <- lapply(input_list, function(x) {
  do.call(myFun, args = x)
})
print(results_list)
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 6
```